# Boost library, how to get neighbouring nodes?

Tags: c++, boost

After generating a graph with `n` nodes, and adding the edges at random, how would I go around getting all the neighbours of a specific node. Is there a function similar to NetworkX's `G.neighbors(i)`?

This is what I've got so far, creating adjacency list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int N = 10000;

    struct status_t{
        typedef vertex_property_tag kind;
    };

    typedef
    property <status_t, string> status;

    typedef
    adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, status> MyGraph;

    MyGraph g (N);

    // add some random edges
    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(100, 153, g);
    add_edge(634, 12, g);
    add_edge(94, 3, g);

    property_map<MyGraph, status_t>::type status_map = get(status_t(), g);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        status_map[i] = "S";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice clean code. Note however that using the custom property is unncessary complicated, you can use property bundles these days: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/134bfbe5805fd0a2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
auto neighbours = boost::adjacent_vertices(94, g);
```

Print them like e.g.

```
for (auto vd : make_iterator_range(neighbours))
    std::cout << "94 has adjacent vertex " << vd << "\n";
```

Prints

```
94 has adjacent vertex 93
94 has adjacent vertex 3
```

If you wanted outgoing edges only, that assumes `directedS` or `bidirectionalS`, in which case you can also do:

```
    for (auto ed : make_iterator_range(boost::out_edges(94, g)))
        std::cout << "outgoing: " << ed << "\n";
    for (auto ed : make_iterator_range(boost::in_edges(94, g)))
        std::cout << "incident: " << ed << "\n";
```

### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb4f75e83b5d8e10)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N = 10000;

    struct status_t { typedef vertex_property_tag kind; };
    typedef property<status_t, string> status;
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS, status> MyGraph;

    MyGraph g(N);

    // add some random edges
    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(100, 153, g);
    add_edge(634, 12, g);

    add_edge(93, 94, g);
    add_edge(94, 3, g);

    property_map<MyGraph, status_t>::type status_map = get(status_t(), g);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        status_map[i] = "S";
    }

    {
        auto neighbours = boost::adjacent_vertices(94, g);
        for (auto vd : make_iterator_range(neighbours))
            std::cout << "94 has adjacent vertex " << vd << "\n";

        // prints
        // for undirected:
        //  94 has adjacent vertex 93
        //  94 has adjacent vertex 3
        // for directed/bidirectionalS:
        //  94 has adjacent vertex 3
    }

    {   // for bidirectionalS:
        for (auto ed : make_iterator_range(boost::out_edges(94, g)))
            std::cout << "outgoing: " << ed << "\n";
        for (auto ed : make_iterator_range(boost::in_edges(94, g)))
            std::cout << "incident: " << ed << "\n";
    }

}
```

Printing

```
94 has adjacent vertex 3
outgoing: (94,3)
incident: (93,94)
```