# Clear vertex of all neighbors of v

Tags: c++, graph, boost

I'm implementing an algorithm in C++ with Boost Graph.

I want to find all the vertex in the neighborhood of v (so, all its neighbors), then change a property of their and finally clear all of their edges.

I found in Boost the function `adjacent_vertices(v,g)` (where v is the vertex and g is the graph) to find all the neighbors. Then I want to apply on all of them the function `clear_vertex(v,g)` (again, v is the vertex and g is the graph) to remove all of their edges.

At this point, I have a problem. The `adjacent_vertices` function returns a pair of `adjacency_iterator`, while for the `clear_vertex` function I need `vertex_iterator` (if I understand correctly how these functions work).

So, there is an easy way to transform the `adjacency_iterator` in `vertex_iterator`? If I keep the `adjacency_iterator` and pass it to the `clear_vertex` function, the problem is that it doesn't remove the edges (or remove them randomly to some vertices).

My **wrong** code is:

```
Graph::adjacency_iterator v,vend;
        for(boost::tie(v,vend) = neighbours; v != vend ; ++v) {
            clear_vertex(*v,g2);
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boost library, how to get neighbouring nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898415/boost-library-how-to-get-neighbouring-nodes)

Comment: Note that adjacent vertices might only include outgoing edges. Check the docs to find whether using `bidirectionalS` changes that

Comment: Acutally, no that doesn't make a difference: https://godbolt.org/z/Kd79G414E

Comment: Ah ok, in fact in my code all works good with directedS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the edge container selectors.

The easiest way is when the containers are node-based, i.e. only the iterators/descriptors to any removed edges are invalidated.

Another way is when you split the "query" and "modification" aspects, e.g.

**[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/o96ds4Ksz)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <random>

void clear_all_neighbours(auto v, auto& g) {
    auto neigh = adjacent_vertices(v, g);
    std::set to_clear(neigh.first, neigh.second);

    for (auto u : to_clear)
        clear_vertex(u, g);
}

int main()
{
    std::mt19937            prng(std::random_device{}());
    boost::adjacency_list<> g;
    generate_random_graph(g, 1000,2000, prng);
    std::cout << "Before: " << num_edges(g) << "\n";

    auto v = vertex(prng() % num_vertices(g), g);
    clear_all_neighbours(v, g);

    std::cout << "After: " << num_edges(g) << "\n";
}
```

Possible output:

```
Before: 2000
After: 1983
```